# MDX Get the average value of top3 members over time

Tags: ssas, mdx, average, query-performance

i am trying to add a calculated measure to my cube. It should calculate the average score of the top 3 children of a specific member (sent as a parameter).
I managed to get the right number but the query takes forever.

can anyone help me improve it?
here is the calculation in an MDX Query:

```
with member AVG_Score_Top3  
 AS Avg(
         Head(
               Order(
                 [OrganizationUnits].[OrganizationUnit Hierarchy].currentMember.children
                 ,score
                 ,BDESC
                )
                ,3
          )
          ,Score
       )
   select  AVG_Score_Top3 on 0,
   [Period].[Periods].[Month Name].members on 1
   from [MyCube]
   where ( [Period].[Year].&[2013],[OrganizationUnits].[OrganizationUnit Heirarchy].[Customer].&[6])
```

thank you very much in advanced

Comment: What is the definition of the `score` measure? Maybe that is the main performance killer?

Comment: I ham using the score measure in many other different calculation. My assumption is that the problem is arround the order function

Comment: Is the described query your real statement and it is slow, or is the real statement more complex than shown? I would not expect a query with a single Order or Topcount to "take forever".

Comment: Yes.  Thats the exact query. I have tried declaring the order of the members as set and run the avg on that set and it improved the performance dramatically.  But the number went wrong - it is not being calculated allong the dates correctly

Comment: I just ran the following on AdventureWorks, and it was fast (one second): `WITH Member AVG_Sales_Top3 AS 
     Avg(TopCount([Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember.Children
                 ,3
                 ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
                 )
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
         )
SELECT { AVG_Sales_Top3 } ON 0,
       Descendants([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2006], [Date].[Calendar].[Month]) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province].&[CA]&[US]` Thus, I still assume `score` is (part of) the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try replacing the score with a different measure.  In addition, an important fact I forgot to mention is that the Organization hierarchy is a Parent-child hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace

```
Head(
     Order(
           [OrganizationUnits].[OrganizationUnit Heirarchy].currentMember.children
          ,score
          ,BDESC
          )
    ,3
    )
```

by

```
TopCount(
          [OrganizationUnits].[OrganizationUnit Heirarchy].currentMember.children
         ,3
         ,score
        )
```

Comment: I actually started with TOPCOUNT turns out to be slower than what i wrote.

Answer (score 1):

could you delete the WHERE clause and replace the content of axis(1) by :

```
exists( [Period].[Periods].[Month Name].members,
        (   [Period].[Year].&[2013],
            [OrganizationUnits].[OrganizationUnit Heirarchy].[Customer].&[6]    ),
        'ScoreMeasureGroupName'
    )
```

and look if performance has improved (and if the results are the same because sometimes the measuregroup widens the range)

Philip,